How to capture a legend event?
Is it possible to capture a legend activation / deactivation event of an echart using a shiny app?
mtcars |> 
head() |> 
tibble::rownames_to_column("model") |> 
e_charts(model) |> 
e_pie(carb) |> 
e_title("Pie chart")


Weclome to SO! Have a look at https://echarts4r.john-coene.com/articles/shiny.html#events.

It's done using a JS callback function on event legendselectchanged.
Here is an example with package echarty:
library(echarty)
plot <- mtcars |> head() |> tibble::rownames_to_column("model") |> 
ec.init( ctype='pie', title=list(text="Pie chart"), legend= list(show=T) )
plot$x$on <- list(list(event='legendselectchanged', 
  handler= ec.clmn("function(ev) { this.setOption({ title:{text:ev.name} }); }")
))
plot

